# Can we create a dynamic phonegap app on the server?

Tags: android, cordova

Given the details about the user, I want a phonegap app created for each and every user having the details they want in that app.

I know we can make a server which can build phonegap apps on server, but is it possible to create a app from scratch on server.?

I am new to phonegap ,searched every corner for this, asked many guys on irc , but didnt get a clue about this.

Please don't mark it as flagged.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the Android half of a web service to do this once.

The basic idea was to write an app that knows how to do everything you want it to do and add some configuration files that control what gets used, themes, strings, etc.

You can then set this up on a CI server, like Hudson or Jenkins or whatever, and generate simple config files on your server, send them to your CI server which will build the app and then retrieve the APK from there afterwards.

Comment: Is it possible on phonegap too.?